# Как изменить ключ в карте(map)?

Tags: java, коллекции, map, java-8, java-stream

**Как можно изменить ключ в мапе?** Делаю все с помощью стримов.
Нужно удалить дату из ключа следующим образом - *BHS2018-05-24=1:13.68799* должно стать = *BHS=1:13.68799* и тд..

Считал данные из 2 файлов и изменил осталось еще изменить ключ

```
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Map.Entry::getKey,
                            Map.Entry::getValue,
                            (v1, v2) -> String.format("%01d:%02d.%d",
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(
                                            Duration.between(LocalTime.parse(v1), LocalTime.parse(v2)).toMillis())
                                            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes
                                            (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(Duration.between(LocalTime.parse(v1), LocalTime.parse(v2)).toMillis())),
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Duration.between(LocalTime.parse(v1), LocalTime.parse(v2)).toMillis())
                                            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(Duration.between(LocalTime.parse(v1), LocalTime.parse(v2)).toMillis())),
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(Duration.between(LocalTime.parse(v1), LocalTime.parse(v2)).toMillis())
                                            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Duration.between(LocalTime.parse(v1), LocalTime.parse(v2)).toMillis())
                                    ))
                    ));
```

Вот map = {BHS2018-05-24=1:13.68799, LHM2018-05-24=1:12.68140, VBM2018-05-24=1:12.68114, DRR2018-05-24=1:12.67693, KMH2018-05-24=1:13.69013, MES2018-05-24=1:13.68885, EOF2018-05-24=1:13.68648, CSR2018-05-24=1:12.68630, RGH2018-05-24=1:12.68610, SSW2018-05-24=1:12.68386, LSW2018-05-24=1:13.68943, SVM2018-05-24=1:12.68143, CLS2018-05-24=1:12.68509, NHR2018-05-24=1:13.68685, FAM2018-05-24=1:12.68337, SPF2018-05-24=1:12.68528, PGS2018-05-24=1:12.68621, SVF2018-05-24=1:04.60575, KRF2018-05-24=1:12.68319}

Пробывал так

```
resultFileTime.forEach((key, value) ->
                    resultFileTime.merge(key, value, (v1, v2) -> key.substring(0, 3)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно!)

```
Map<String, String> result = resultFileTime.entrySet().stream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(s->s.getKey().substring(0,3), s->s.getValue()));
```